# How to activate an Excel file without knowing the full name?

Tags: excel, vba, file

I am downloading an Excel file which changes name every day with random numbers at the end.

I am taking the data and copying it in my masterfile. I've got the copy/paste.

Is there a way to code it other than Activesheet. I don't want the specific Excel file open and selected when I run my macro as we usually have multiple Excel files open.

Is there a way to select the Excel file without knowing the full name?

Here is the whole code I have:

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Updates ...
' Change PartialWorkbookName and the value of cStrPartial (the string).
'*******************************************************************************
Sub PartialWorkbookName()
  Const cStrPartial As String = "Task_States_(Pivot)"
  Dim objWb As Workbook
  For Each objWb In Workbooks
    If Left(objWb.Name, Len(cStrPartial)) = cStrPartial Then Exit For
  Next
  If objWb Is Nothing Then GoTo NotFound
  With objWb
'*******************************************************************************
' Code in here

.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Select
'going from horasphere data status+date, making it readable by converting it with the comma and pasting it into your masterfile table.
'have to find a way to have the macro find the file without a name as the name will always change.

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
        ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    'this top part is to make the data readable by going into Data - Text to columns - etc

    'To copy paste the readable data into the masterfile to run the 1st macro
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'Selects all dirty cell in the worksheet that is currently opened only, may need to tweak this later on
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Selection.Copy

    'pastes it into the blank sheet
    Windows("macro").Activate
    Sheets(3).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'deletes the table (have to eventually put that at the beginning of my macro)
    Sheets(1).Select
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


    Sheets(3).Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(3).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets(1).Select

'*******************************************************************************
  End With
  Set objWb = Nothing
Exit Sub
NotFound:
  MsgBox "Workbook not found."
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

Comment: How are you downloading the file - using code, or manually?  If you needed to manually locate and select the file, what *exact* steps would you take?

Comment: I don't know if you have noticed, but I edited my answer 3 days ago adding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Workbook Name

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Updates ...
' Change PartialWorkbookName and the value of cStrPartial (the string).
'*******************************************************************************
Sub PartialWorkbookName()
  Const cStrPartial As String = "Book_20"
  Dim objWb As Workbook
  For Each objWb In Workbooks
    If Left(objWb.Name, Len(cStrPartial)) = cStrPartial Then Exit For
  Next
  If objWb Is Nothing Then GoTo NotFound
  With objWb
'*******************************************************************************
' Code in here

'*******************************************************************************
  End With
  Set objWb = Nothing
Exit Sub
NotFound:
  MsgBox "Workbook not found."
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

You can reduce it (not recommended) to this:

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Updates ...
' Change PartialWorkbookNameReduced and the value of cStrPartial (the string).
'*******************************************************************************
Sub PartialWorkbookNameReduced(): Const cStrPartial As String = "Book_20"
  Dim objWb As Workbook: For Each objWb In Workbooks
      If Left(objWb.Name, Len(cStrPartial)) = cStrPartial Then Exit For
    Next: If objWb Is Nothing Then GoTo NotFound
  With objWb
'*******************************************************************************
' Code in here

'*******************************************************************************
  End With: Set objWb = Nothing: Exit Sub
NotFound: MsgBox "Workbook not found."
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

Additionally you can put the Dim line in the first line but it exceeds the 80 char limit, so I didn't do it.

## EDIT:

> - In TextToColumns I have removed all arguments with default parameters.
> - If you compare this code with your code you can see the logic how    this was done. So if an error occurs you can easily revert the part
>     where the error occurred.
> - Whatever is happening in the downloaded file is happening on a sheet    named "Sheet1", between the following two lines:

```
With objWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

End With
```

> - And what's happening in the workbook where this code resides is    happening between the following two lines:

```
With ThisWorkbook

End With
```

---

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Updates ...
' Change PartialWorkbookName and the value of cStrPartial (the string).
'*******************************************************************************
Sub PartialWorkbookNamedsf()
  Const cStrPartial As String = "Task_States_(Pivot)"
  Dim objWb As Workbook
  For Each objWb In Workbooks
    If Left(objWb.Name, Len(cStrPartial)) = cStrPartial Then Exit For
  Next
  If objWb Is Nothing Then GoTo NotFound
'*******************************************************************************
  With objWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' going from horasphere data status+date, making it readable by converting
    ' it with the comma and pasting it into your masterfile table.
    ' have to find a way to have the macro find the file without a name as
    ' the name will always change.
    .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), _
        Tab:=True, Comma:=True, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, FieldInfo:= _
        Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), _
        Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
        Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), _
        Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1))
    ' this top part is to make the data readable by going into
    ' Data - Text to columns - etc

    ' To copy paste the readable data into the masterfile to run
    ' the 1st macro
    .Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp

    ' Selects all dirty cell in the worksheet that is currently opened only,
    ' may need to tweak this later on
    .UsedRange.Copy

  End With

  With ThisWorkbook

    ' pastes it into the blank sheet
    .Sheets(3).Range("A1").Paste
    ' deletes the table (eventually put this at the beginning of my macro)
    .Sheets(1).Rows(3).End(xlDown).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    .Sheets(3).Rows(1).End(xlDown).Copy Destination:=.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
    .Sheets(3).Cells.ClearContents
    .Sheets(1).Select

  End With
'*******************************************************************************
  Set objWb = Nothing
Exit Sub
NotFound:
  MsgBox "Workbook not found."
End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```

Comment: What about just looking for the newest file in the folder? Or as well? Not picking on you, just a thought... plus 1 anyway.

Comment: @Solar Mike: Thx. But if OP uses ActiveSheet, I figured he has the downloaded file already open, and now he opens the WB with the macro but e.g. suddenly he remembers he wanted to lookup something in an other WS or a  third open WB and after he's finished goes back to the macro-containing WB and cllick oh,.... he executed the macro on the wrong WS or WB. I think he's trying to prevent something like this.

Comment: @VBasic2008, thanks for your answer. I've tried it out and it doesn't give me any errors, but it still seems to be giving me the same issue. Maybe I'm missing something here? When I add my code in the middle, it does the operation on the selected and opened worksheet, even though my worksheet with the partial name is opened in the background (it just isn't the selected file at the moment.) I've added the partial name of my worksheet in the cStrPartial. Anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: You refer to the "cStrPartial" workbook with objWb and to its ActiveSheet with .ActiveSheet (notice the ".") or if you're using sheetnames you have to use .Worksheets("Sheet1") when you're referring to the downloaded workbook. And to refer to the workbook where the code is you use ThisWorkbook. E.g. If you want to copy a range you use .ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2").Copy ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B7:C8"). You can check if my code works by adding to the beginning of your code 'Debug.Print .Name' and it should print the full name of the workbook in the immediate window (or MsgBox .Name).

Comment: Why don't you post your original code and if it was working before I'll have it working in no time.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Hi, here is part of my code as I can't put it all, that I want to use. I need to be able to select the excel file that is already opened with the partial name somehow to get the data and paste it into my masterfile.

Comment: Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
        ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True @VBasic2008

Comment: If you use my code, then use '.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Select'. Notice the dot infront of Activesheet ("."). Or use the Sheet Name of the downloaded file e.g. '.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Select'.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Hi, tried it exactly as you've said, by using your code and then adding '.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Select' where you wrote 'code in here and then adding my code right after. Still doesn't work. I now get the ''Run time error 1004'' -Select method of range failed. It almost seems like I have the same problem, where it's not selecting my downloaded excel file that's running in the background. Any idea?

Comment: Do you know that you can edit your question? Just click on edit below your post and post the whole code with my code. When editing select the whole code and use the braces {} sign and it will be in code format. If this is a problem then I can't help you anymore. Send my a comment so I can see that you have posted the code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 , Hi, sorry, didn't actually know you could do that. I'm new to stackoverflow and VBA as a whole. Thanks again for all your help, really appreciate it. My whole code is in my answer now under ''Here is the whole code I have right now :''

Comment: Does the code before windows macro happening in the downloaded file? What's the name of the sheet in the downloaded file? What is the full name of macro (macro.xls or)? Is the rest of the code happening in macro? Are sheets 1 and 3 in macro? Is this code in macro?

Comment: @VBasic2008, So essentially the code before windoes macro is whats supposed to happend in the downloaded file as you've already guessed. The name of the sheet1 in the downloaded file is ''Task_States_(Pivot)_2018-12-10_'' The name of the macro file is macro.xlsm, the rest of the code is happening in macro, yes. The only part that needs to happen in the downloaded file is the part before windows macro. Sheets 1 and 3 are indeed in macro. The code is in macro as well, yes.

Comment: @VBasic2008 let me know when you have time.